# f:ajax not rendering the input field giving malformedXML: During update: tr_j_idt34_Postscript not found

Tags: jsf-2

iam using JSF2 and i am using f:ajax for rendering the inputtext but the inputtext is not rendering can any one please help on this.
JSF

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF 2.0, malformedXML when using ajax on a commandlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556245/jsf-2-0-malformedxml-when-using-ajax-on-a-commandlink)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you had given some code and the full stack trace. But a simple google search of your query gives the following answer:

Inside the ajax tag you need to give the id of the component to be rendered. For more information you can see BalusC's answer:

[JSF 2.0, malformedXML when using ajax on a commandlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556245/jsf-2-0-malformedxml-when-using-ajax-on-a-commandlink)